# How to embed query parameter in the linked page url of webview before its gets loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

We need to add query parameter (isfromMobile=true ) in every webpage URL, which is required to identify that the request is from the mobile app at the backend. it's absolutely fine loading on the first page, however, if I click on the link inside webview the url changes which is completely a new URL for backend system, As per the logic, mobile app should embed query parameter on this URL as well. I tried fixing the same with following delegate method of webview.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    request.url = request.url?.getMobileUrl() // this adds the query parameter in url eg : testurl?isFromMobile=true
    return true
}
```

However, I observed the request parameter is not mutable in this delegate, creating everytime a new request will definitely increase the web URL loading time or I would not prefer that. Any better suggestion for the same.

Answer (score 2):

First, do use `WKWebView`. Then you can tap into WKNavigationDelegate `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` method to check for the loading url and if it doesn't have your required query parameters adjust the url and reload it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    var loadUrl = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/tags?isFromMobile=true")!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // .. all your other code here

        // Load first request with initial url
        loadWebPage(url: loadUrl)
    }

    func loadWebPage(url: URL)  {
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    components?.query = nil

        // If already has a query then append a param
        // otherwise create a new one
        if let query = url.query {
            // If isFromMobile param already exists jsut reassign the existing query
            if query.contains("isFromMobile=true") {
                components?.query = query
            } else {
                 components?.query = query + "&isFromMobile=true"
            }
        } else {
            components?.query = "isFromMobile=true"
        }

        let customRequest = URLRequest(url: components!.url!)
        loadUrl = components!.url!
        webView!.load(customRequest)
    }

    // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        // If url changes, cancel current request which has no custom parameters
        // and load a new request with that url with custom parameters
        if url != loadUrl {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            loadWebPage(url: url)
         } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But, I need to provide support for the lower versions as well and need to maintain the webview stack(user should be able to come back previous ) as well.

Comment: Seriously, you need to support lower than iOS 8?

Comment: I wish I could provide support above iOS 8  version only.

Comment: very nice approach but this will start appending isFromMobile=true with all the urls in your webpage and then load them which you might do not want, if you only want to append this parameter with your main url , this thread can help [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408420/getting-the-link-url-tapped-in-wkwebview

Comment: It is not very difficult to check to which URL you want to append the parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while searching around in the apple documentation, I have found multiple things.

First of all, you are using the UIWebview which is deprecated. You should use WKWebView. From the [docs:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

> Important
>   Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

When searching the documentation for the WKWebView, there is a method you could use, called [load(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414954-load).

So you would override this method, change the url to contain the (isFromMobile=true) and then call the super method with the updated url.

Hope this could help.